# Rails strong params TypeError no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Why am I getting this error?:

> TypeError (no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer)

in the create action in the posts_controller:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
@post = @character.posts.create(post_params)
...

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit( conversation_attributes: [ missives_attributes: [ :content ] ] )
end
```

**post.rb**

```
has_one :conversation, class_name: 'Postconversation', dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation
```

**postconversation.rb**

```
has_many :missives, class_name: 'Postmissive', dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :missives
```

**_post_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :conversation_attributes do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.fields_for :missives_attributes do |fff| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :callsign, character.callsign %>
    <%= fff.text_area :content %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Logs**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mxHD...VoA==", "callsign"=>"baz", "post"=>{"conversation_attributes"=>{"missives_attributes"=>{"content"=>"Hello"}}}}
```

**EDIT**

According to this question, it looks like I need square brackets around my submitted parameters:
[Strong parameters with has_many gives "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18918337/strong-parameters-with-has-many-gives-no-implicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-int?rq=1)

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mxHD...VoA==", "callsign"=>"baz", "post"=>{"conversation_attributes"=> [ {"missives_attributes"=> [ {"content"=>"Hello"} ] } ] }}
```

But how do I achieve this in the post form??

Comment: Should'nt this `<%= f.text_area :content %>` be `<%= fff.text_area :content %>`

Comment: Just a guess: `missives` is a `has_many` relation thus in your params it is treated as an array with `:content` taken as the array index (which should be an integer and not a symbol).

Comment: Shouldn't it be `f.fields_for :conversation` and `ff.fields_for :missives`, without `_attributes`?

Comment: That's what I thought originally, but other SO answers seemed to suggest otherwise. Without `_attributes`, I get this error: `Unpermitted parameter :conversation`

Comment: What is in your form_for (or form_with)? Did you defined it for @post or just :post?

Comment: Just :post. `<%= form_for(:post, url: :posts, method: :post, html: { class: "post_form", id: "message_form" } ) do |f| %> `

Comment: @StephanWiehr Thank you, I've tried putting {} brackets in various positions but I either get exactly the same error message or it breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Since, `missives_attributes` contain `content`

You shld use, `<%= fff.text_area :content %>` for `missives_attributes` and not `<%= f.text_area :content %>`

```
<%= f.fields_for :conversation_attributes do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.fields_for :missives_attributes do |fff| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :callsign, character.callsign %>
    <%= fff.text_area :content %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes, you're quite right, I've corrected this mistake, but the original TypeError remains.

Comment: can you paste more error` and the `contoller` method where it is `cmng`

Comment: It isn't solved, I'm getting so desperate I'm actually considering the historically useless tactic of offering a bounty.

Comment: On which method it was cmng, `create` or `show`? can you please check the place where it is cmng

Comment: It's in the `create` method. Nothing special happens before the line `@post = @character.posts.create(post_params)`. I'm baffled.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
@post = @character.posts.create(post_params)
...

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit( conversation_attributes: [ missives_attributes: [ :content ] ] )
end
```

**post.rb**

```
has_one :conversation, class_name: 'Postconversation', dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :post
accepts_nested_attributes_for :conversation
```

**postconversation.rb**

```
belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :conversation
has_many :missives, class_name: 'Postmissive', dependent: :destroy, foreign_key: 'conversation_id', inverse_of: :conversation
accepts_nested_attributes_for :missives
```

**postmissive.rb**

```
belongs_to :conversation, class_name: 'Postconversation', foreign_key: 'conversation_id', inverse_of: :missives
validates :conversation, presence: true # validates :conversation_id does not work
```

**_post_form.html.erb**

```
<%= f.fields_for :conversation_attributes do |ff| %>
  <%= ff.fields_for 'missives_attributes[]', Postmissive.new do |fff| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :callsign, character.callsign %>
    <%= fff.text_area :content %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**Submitted Parameters**

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"mxHD...VoA==", "callsign"=>"baz", "post"=>{"conversation_attributes"=>{"missives_attributes"=>[{"content"=>"Hello"}]}}}
```

**Notes**

1) Note the addition of `inverse_of:` so Rails recognises the bi-directional association. The database save fails without this. The docs say it's only necessary to use with `has_one` and `has_many`, but some Stack Overflow answers say it should also be used with the `belongs_to`, so that's what I've done (`belongs_to :post, inverse_of: :conversation` and `belongs_to :conversation, inverse_of: :missives`). Further insight on this welcome.

2) `post_params` are fine as is. No need for the addition of any brackets.

3) In `postmissive.rb`, the validation had to be `validates :conversation`, not `validates :conversation_id`.

4) Stephan Wiehr was right, the `missives_attributes` had to be submitted as an array. Thanks to Kartikey Tanna for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50648375/346613) answer on how to achieve this.